# A computer lab probability

Tags: probability

A computer lab has 30 computers. Each of the computer has a 90% chance of working. If a class of 30 students are taken into the lab, what's the probability that 25 students will get working computers.

So this is a type of probability question that I've legit never solved before...so I have no idea how to begin solving it...Help please!

Comment: Which subject is that?

Comment: To encourage others to help you, you should provide context such as what course you're taking (if any), what text you're reading (if any), what specific topic (think "binomial theorem" rather than "probability") you're studying (if any), what other formulas you know that might be applicable, etc.  Bare questions without this context are prone to being downvoted and closed.

Comment: If you know about the binomial distribution you're in good hands.